# Random word popup script using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, random

So I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/redler/QcUPk/8/) already on here and it's almost exactly what I want. The only difference is that instead of creating  boxes, I'd like for them to be words taken from an array - like

```
var textarray = [
    "wow",
    "so amaze",
    "much hunt",
    "such treasure"];
```

So that instead of colored boxes popping up randomly it would be one of those random words randomly colored. Here is the code from the jsfiddle.

```
(function makeDiv(){
    var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
    var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
    $newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
        'width':divsize+'px',
        'height':divsize+'px',
        'background-color': color
    });

    var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

    $newdiv.css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':posx+'px',
        'top':posy+'px',
        'display':'none'
    }).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(100).delay(300).fadeOut(200, function(){
       $(this).remove();
       makeDiv(); 
    }); 
})();
```

Comment: So you should just change 'background-color' with 'color', remove that divsize, and use math.random to call a random number between 1 and the length of your array, and put the value from the array to a variable, that you "add" in a div.
These are just quick tips, I'm sure you can do it by yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

How is this?
http://jsfiddle.net/x2EXz/1/
(comments about changes listed in-line below)

```
var textArray = [
    "wow",
    "so amaze",
    "much hunt",
    "such treasure"];

function makeDiv(){
    var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
    var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
    $newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
        'width': ' 30 px', // sets width to constant
        'height': '10px', // sets height to constant

    // removes background-color property of div, but keeps
    // generating random colors that will be applied to the random words
    //    'background-color': color

    });

    // randomWord will accommodate for textArray of any size
    var randomWord = textArray[ (Math.floor(Math.random() * textArray.length)) ]
    var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

    // appends randomWord to new div
    $newdiv.text(randomWord).css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':posx+'px',
        'top':posy+'px',
        'display':'none',
        // adds randomly generated color to random word
        'color' : color 
    }).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(100).delay(300).fadeOut(200, function(){
       $(this).remove();
       makeDiv(); 
    }); 
}


makeDiv();
```

Comment: Hello, if you found any of the answers useful, please select one as the official answer. Building reputations helps a lot on this site. Thank you!